# wxRuby Segfaults When Trying to Run Main Loop

Tags: ruby, rubygems, segmentation-fault, wxwidgets, wxruby

I'm trying to run wxRuby with Ruby 1.9, but I can't start up the application without getting a segfault. Even the small minimal application suggested on the website (code used is below) won't run.

```
require "wx"
include Wx

class MinimalApp < App
  def on_init
    Frame.new(nil, -1, "Test").show
  end
end

MinimalApp.new.main_loop
```

The program, when ran with `ruby test.rb`, crashes with the following message:

```
ruby 1.9.2p320 (2012-04-20 revision 35421) [x86_64-linux]

-- control frame ----------
c:0004 p:---- s:0009 b:0009 l:000008 d:000008 CFUNC  :main_loop
c:0003 p:0066 s:0006 b:0006 l:001078 d:0007a8 EVAL   test.rb:10
c:0002 p:---- s:0004 b:0004 l:000003 d:000003 FINISH
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 b:0002 l:001078 d:001078 TOP   
---------------------------
-- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------
test.rb:10:in `<main>'
test.rb:10:in `main_loop'

-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------
/home/vinny/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/libruby.so.1.9(rb_vm_bugreport+0x5e) [0x7f8ae7464b9e]
/home/vinny/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x64234) [0x7f8ae7340234]
/home/vinny/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/libruby.so.1.9(rb_bug+0xa5) [0x7f8ae73410c5]
/home/vinny/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x118c04) [0x7f8ae73f4c04]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0() [0x3b6e80efe0]
/lib64/libwx_baseu-2.8.so.0(_ZN7wxMutex6UnlockEv+0) [0x3b790e4390]
/lib64/libwx_gtk2u_core-2.8.so.0() [0x3b7a9e452b]
/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0() [0x3b70047964]
/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0(g_main_loop_run+0x72) [0x3b70047dc2]
/lib64/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0(gtk_main+0xa7) [0x3b7b54ac57]
/lib64/libwx_gtk2u_core-2.8.so.0(_ZN11wxEventLoop3RunEv+0x48) [0x3b7a9f81d8]
/lib64/libwx_gtk2u_core-2.8.so.0(_ZN9wxAppBase8MainLoopEv+0x4c) [0x3b7aa6a30c]
/lib64/libwx_gtk2u_core-2.8.so.0(_ZN5wxApp10InitializeERiPPw+0x371) [0x3b7a9e4a41]
/lib64/libwx_baseu-2.8.so.0(_Z12wxEntryStartRiPPw+0x7e) [0x3b7909745e]
/lib64/libwx_baseu-2.8.so.0(_Z12wxInitializeiPPw+0x3c) [0x3b7909776c]
/lib64/libwx_baseu-2.8.so.0(_Z7wxEntryRiPPw+0x1a) [0x3b7909788a]
/home/vinny/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/wxruby-ruby19-2.0.0-x86_64-linux/lib/wxruby2.so(+0x21b403) [0x7f8ae00cb403]
/home/vinny/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x181d8c) [0x7f8ae745dd8c]
/home/vinny/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x17a142) [0x7f8ae7456142]
/home/vinny/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x17e430) [0x7f8ae745a430]
/home/vinny/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/libruby.so.1.9(rb_iseq_eval_main+0xb0) [0x7f8ae7460330]
/home/vinny/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x6a59a) [0x7f8ae734659a]
/home/vinny/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/libruby.so.1.9(ruby_exec_node+0x1d) [0x7f8ae73475bd]
/home/vinny/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/libruby.so.1.9(ruby_run_node+0x1c) [0x7f8ae734954c]
ruby(main+0x4b) [0x40088b]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5) [0x3b6e421735]
ruby() [0x4008b9]

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

Aborted (core dumped)
```

I have tried this on both Ruby 1.9.3p194 and 1.9.2p320 (the log for the latter shown above), both with the same result. I haven't tested on Ruby 1.8, but I'd rather not have to use 1.8 in order to run wxRuby.

My Ruby versions are managed with RVM and the wxRuby version installed is 2.0.0 (gem name- wxruby-ruby19) (2.0.1 isn't available for 64-bit Linux).

I have verified in irb that "wx" can be required successfully, but as soon as the main_loop method is run, it crashes.

My operating system is Fedora 17 x64, and I have the wxGTK 2.8.12 package installed for use with C++, if that makes a difference.

Comment: I used wxRuby on a project about two years ago, first with ruby 1.8 and then with an upgrade to 1.9.  It was crashy even back then, and there hasn't been an official update since.  My advice is to ditch it and forget you ever looked at it.